# Como pegar o usuário logado na máquina que está acessando a página PHP?

Tags: php, apache, active-directory

Preciso pegar o usuário que está logado na máquina que está sendo usada para acessar uma certa página PHP. A página PHP está sendo servida por um Apache.
Através de algumas pesquisas, encontrei na documentação do PHP as seguintes chaves $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"] e $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] que a princípio teriam a informação de que preciso, mas estas não estão sendo retornadas pelo Apache.
Existe alguma configuração no Apache ou alguma forma de ter essa informação com PHP?

Comment: Dependendo do ambiente o Apache pode estar passando por um proxy Você pode fazer como sugerido em:
https://renaudmarti.net/posts/make-apache-proxy-remote-user-to-backend/ No seu .htaccess adicione o seguinte RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.*) RewriteRule .* - [E=X_REMOTE_USER:%1] RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{X_REMOTE_USER}e

Comment: Configurando o apache de forma que se comunique com o domínio já é o suficiente para identificar o usuário que acessa o site? Isso irá pedir a autenticação do usuário no acesso?